# adding \label{} in kable kableExtra latex output

Tags: r, latex, kable, kableextra

I am trying to create a latex formatted table in R with a \label{} option.

Something similar to

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

data_frame(a = 1:3, b = 2:4) %>% 
  kable(align = 'c', format = 'latex') %>% 
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)
```

the resulting output is below, but i would like to add the \label{label_value} parameter to the latex table with a label_value I can define

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
a & b\\
\hline
1 & 2\\
\hline
2 & 3\\
\hline
3 & 4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I am trying to automatically create tables in R which I can save and then include in a latex document

Comment: where is the `\label` parameter placed? You can manually edit the output of kable like a regular string. You just need to make sure you give the resulting strings the attributes from the original output

Comment: looks like gsub() can work nicely to edit the automatic label created when using the caption argument and still retain the attributes. Thanks for the suggestions OganM

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you put a caption in the call to `kable`, you'll get a label automatically, based on the name you give to the code chunk.
If you are running it at the top level as in your example, it's kind of clunky:  you need put the label in your caption, and you'll get two labels, yours and the auto-generated useless one.  For example,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

data_frame(a = 1:3, b = 2:4) %>% 
  kable(align = 'c', format = 'latex', 
       caption = "Table caption \\label{tab:example}") %>% 
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)
```

which produces

```
\begin{table}[t]

\caption{\label{tab:}Table caption \label{tab:example}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
\hline
a & b\\
\hline
1 & 2\\
\hline
2 & 3\\
\hline
3 & 4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I'm not sure, but I'd expect in some circumstances you'd need to manually edit out the auto-generated label `\label{tab:}`.  So use knitr or R-markdown and avoid the problem.

Comment: great solution user2554330. I'm currently writing a manuscript in Tex Shop with tables/graphics produced in R so I was looking for an easy way to automate incorporating the table and graphics and this works well. I don't know that creating the manuscript in R-markdown would work as well for me, but a good suggestion too.

Comment: You can use Sweave-style knitr in TeXShop if you install a custom engine.  (Don't use Sweave, use knitr.)  It will automatically generate the label.  If you can't find or figure out the code for the engine, post another question, but maybe not on Stackoverflow:  tex.stackexchange.com would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `knitr::opts_current` to control the automatic label generated with the caption:

```
> library(knitr)
> library(kableExtra)
> opts_current$set(label = "hello")
> data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 2:4) %>% 
+     kable(align = 'c', format = 'latex', 
+           caption = "Table caption") %>% 
+     kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)
\begin{table}

\caption{\label{tab:hello}Table caption}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{c|c}
\hline
a & b\\
\hline
1 & 2\\
\hline
2 & 3\\
\hline
3 & 4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: That's interesting:  the `knitr::opts_current` help page says that `opts_current$set` does nothing.  I guess that's only true in a `knitr` document, not in top level code.

Answer (score 7):

There's a built-in option for that.

```
kable(..., label = "something")
```

More info at: https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues/486

Comment: I like it, but doesn't give you enough control, because it prefixes with a "tab:" text.